# .htaccess rewrite rules for multiple sites

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

### Scenario

I have 3 domain names:

1. www.hellokitty.com
2. www.keroro.com
3. www.doraemon.com

I want to host all of them in one web hosting with the following directories:

1. ./htdocs/hellokitty.com/
2. ./htdocs/keroro.com/
3. ./htdocs/doraemon.com/

All of them are linked to the same hosting server with A record.

However, my hosting do not support virtual host.

I need .htaccess files to rewrite the URLs

So, I tried in this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?hellokitty.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hellokitty\.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hellokitty\.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?hellokitty.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ hellokitty.com/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?keroro.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/keroro\.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /keroro\.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?keroro.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ keroro.com/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?doraemon.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/doraemon\.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /doraemon\.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?doraemon.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ doraemon.com/index.php [L]
```

Thus, if I go to www.hellokitty.com, it rewrites to ./htdocs/hellokitty.com/ internally.

### Problem

If I go to **www.hellokitty.com/hellokitty.com/**

Or, if I go to **www.hellokitty.com/keroro.com/**, it still works

So, my problem is that how to prevent the client direct access the above real URLs and show a 404 error to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(hellokitty|keroro)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```